# How to parse Html by Agility into a string in C#?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

Could anyone please help to parse Html with Agility pack into a single string ?

I'm trying to parse Html similar to following format,

```
<blockquote>\n
    <p>Here is the first collection:<\/p>\n 
        <ol>\n 
            <li>List1<\/li>\n 
            <li>List2<\/li>\n 
            <li>List3<\/li>\n 
        <\/ol>\n 
    <p>Here is the second collection:<\/p>\n 
        <ol>\n 
            <li>List1<\/li>\n 
            <li>List2<\/li>\n 
        <\/ol>\n 
<\/blockquote>
```

I try to use following method to get "p" and "li" and "blockquote". 
However, method .Descendants creates individual collections for "p", "li", and "blockquote", but I need to put individual element in sequence and store them in a single string.

```
 IEnumerable<HtmlNode> h3Tags = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("p"); foreach (var h3tag in h3Tags) {}
```

for instance, I want my string stores, 
"Here is the first collection: List1 List2 List3 Here is the second collection List1 List2".

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *InnerText* property of the *blockquote* node. That should return the strings in expected order.

Do something like

```
var blockQuoteNode = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("blockquote").First(); // or do a document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(//put the exact xpath value of the blockquote element here...)
var stringsYouNeed = blockQuoteNode.InnerText;
```

Comment: Sorry, I make the question more clear. What if I have blockquote contains multiple "p" and "li"? because .First() only returns the very first node. Thanks!

Comment: The .First() will return the entire first blockquote node object, including all its child elements. These child elements are just other nodes that could be of type p and li. Keep in mind that the .First() method is just used to access the first node in a collection of descendant nodes (in this case, blockquote) in the document root node. You can specify which node or specify a specific xpath value to select the blockquote node that you want. Also if you give it a try, you'll notice that the InnerText property returns all the inner text property values of the node and of its child nodes.